# Earthquake As A Verb

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Is there a way to use earthquake as a verb, i.e.:

It started earthquaking...

What's the proper way to express earthquake as a verb?

Comment: drop the 'earth' and bam! it's a verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from *tremble*, you could also use *quake*, and say:

> *The earth started to quake...*

[**quake**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quake): to shake or tremble, as from shock or instability: *The earth quaked*

Comment: The earth can "quake" for reasons other than an earthquake.

Comment: @Kris For what other reasons?

Comment: @Araucaria For instance, a big explosion could cause the earth to quake/tremble/shake. (I personally think one will want to carefully consider the choice of words if describing a non-earthquake quaking of the earth, though.)

Answer (score 0):

You suggest you say:

> everything started to tremble, shake, move, ( because of the earthquake) or,
>
> the earthquake (seism or temblor) stared and shook everything.

Answer (score 0):

*[Earthquake](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/earthquake)* is a noun, not a verb. It has not been 'verbed' in general English writing.

No, you cannot say "It started earthquaking … "

One way to say it could be:

> "There started an earthquake."

If you know the intensity, you could say:

> The earth started to tremble
>   The earth started to shake violently

Comment: Regarding the idea of 'verbing' the noun "earthquake", wouldn't doing so be almost entirely redundant considering that "earthquake" is derived from a 'nouned' verb? I like @Elian's answer as it just breaks "earthquake" up in its components, changing very little, but does it come across as unnatural in any way?

Comment: @Kris Your first example seems very ungrammatical to me or at least incredibly awkward. I stuck it in a search engine as "there started an earthquake" and only one hit came up - and that one was your example here on ELU.

Comment: @Araucaria https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=bkeUU8zpKMqUuATKkYGADA&ved=0CBkQ1S4#q=%22there+started+an+%22&tbm=bks

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist See my comment at Elian's answer.

Comment: @Kris Point taken -ish. I think the reason it comes across as awkward here is that this construction requires a long NP to warrant postposing the subject. Compare. ***At lunch there started a fight. Later I asked..*** with ***After lunch there started a fight which would irrevocably change the nature of their relationship forever***

Comment: @Kris nonetheless point taken :)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be said about a stomach if you're hungry. Just heard it in the animated movie "Soul". It says, "Your stomach is earthquaking".

Comment: I suspect that the movie might be the only usage of earthquake in that context.